# how to increment the value of a progress bar when press a button javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

this is a very simple program that when you press the button the value inside the progress bar increases until it reaches the 100%.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>example</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="w3-container">

  <h2>dynamic Progress bar</h2>
  <p>example:</p>

  <div class="w3-light-grey">
    <div id="myBar" class="w3-container w3-green w3-center" style="width:20%">20%</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button class="w3-button w3-green" onclick="move()">Click Me</button> 
</div>

<script>
function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
    var width = 20;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

when you press the button whatever is the value inside the progressbar (eg 10% 20%) it reaches the 100%. i would that when i press the button, the value increases only only by a certain quantity (for example if the value is 10% and i press the button i want that the value will arrive at 20%).

Thanks to everyone!!

Comment: This code is pretty much a straight copy and paste from W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp

Show what you have tried yourself, then maybe we will be able to help you!

Here's a hint, `setInterval(frame, 10)` is going to call the `frame()` function every 10ms, and therefore keep updating the progress bar...

Comment: So set the end point..... instead of 100, put it to the value you want.

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to remove the setInterval, since it will call the function again without having to click on button.

This code simply define width outside of function, and then on each click, increment width by 10 and change the progress bar style.

```js
var width = 20;

function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    if (width < 100) {
      width+=10;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>example</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<body>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <h2>dynamic Progress bar</h2>
    <p>example:</p>
    <div class="w3-light-grey">
      <div id="myBar" class="w3-container w3-green w3-center" style="width:20%">20%</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="w3-button w3-green" onclick="move()">Click Me</button>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While this is a solution, it removes the sliding effect which is done via the setInterval, it shouldn't be removed but instead be cleared when the width reaches the desired number. Sidenote: not my down vote.

Comment: Well, the fact is that I was editing my answer to add the sliding effect, but the editor kept telling me about wrong indented so I give up: But you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and simple way to do it with minimal changes, firstly you need to declare a global variable that holds the value of the "width-to-be". This is the desired width of the progress bar, once the animation has finished.

Next for the sake of clarity, I changed the name of the 'width' variable to *widthAnim*. When the value of *widthValue* is changed, *widthAnim* will increment until it reaches that same value.

The *widthIncrement* variable change be changed to whatever you like, and it will increment by that amount.

Finally, I added at extra condition in the frame function that makes sure it only goes up in increments of *widthIncrement*.

```js
var widthValue = 20;

function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var widthAnim = widthValue;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  var widthIncrement = 10;

  widthValue = widthAnim + widthIncrement;

  function frame() {
    if (widthAnim >= widthValue || widthValue > 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      widthAnim++;
      elem.style.width = widthAnim + '%';
      elem.innerHTML = widthAnim * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>example</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<body>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <h2>dynamic Progress bar</h2>
    <p>example:</p>
    <div class="w3-light-grey">
      <div id="myBar" class="w3-container w3-green w3-center" style="width:20%">20%</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="w3-button w3-green" onclick="move()">Click Me</button>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified some of your code, when attach the 100% it will clear the counter and restart from 0%.

maybe help you :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>example</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="w3-container">

  <h2>dynamic Progress bar</h2>
  <p>example:</p>

  <div class="w3-light-grey">
    <div id="myBar" class="w3-container w3-green w3-center" style="width:20%">20%</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button class="w3-button w3-green" onclick="move()">Click Me</button> 
</div>

<script>
function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
    var width = parseInt(elem.innerHTML);
    var aim = width + 10;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    
    function frame() {
        if (width >= aim) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else if(width >= 100) {
            width=0; 
            aim = 10;
            elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        } else {
            width++;
            elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
            elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set an initial value of `width` for example `20` and keep increasing it in `setInterval` callback till it is `40` (you can check that by taking its remainder with 20) and so on.

```
 if(width % 20 === 0 ) clearInterval(id)
```

Here is snippet

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
var width = 20;
var id = null;
var click = false;
function move() {
if(!click){
  click = true;
  id = setInterval(function() {
    width++;
    if (width > 100) width = 20;
    if (width % 20 === 0){
    clearInterval(id);
    click = false;
    }
    elem.style.width = width + '%';
    elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
  }, 30);
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>example</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<body>
  <div class="w3-container">

    <h2>dynamic Progress bar</h2>
    <p>example:</p>

    <div class="w3-light-grey">
      <div id="myBar" class="w3-container w3-green w3-center" style="width:20%">20%</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="w3-button w3-green" onclick="move()">Click Me</button>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you click the "Click Me" button twice, your progress bar will just continuously update and reset.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired result you should call `clearInterval(id)` when `width` is a multiple of 10. This will stop the `frame()` function from being called until the `move()` function is called again (when the user clicks the button)

To determine if width is a multiple of 10 the remainder operator can be used:

```
if (width % 10 == 0) {
    clearInterval(id);
}
```

`width` should also be a global variable, outside of the `move()` function so that progress can be tracked in between button clicks.

```js
var width = 20;
var id = null;

function move() {
  if (width == 100) {
      return;
  }

  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");

  if (id) {
      clearInterval(id);
  }

  id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    width ++;
    elem.style.width = width + '%';
    elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';

    if (width % 10 == 0) {
      clearInterval(id);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>example</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<body>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <h2>dynamic Progress bar</h2>
    <p>example:</p>
    <div class="w3-light-grey">
      <div id="myBar" class="w3-container w3-green w3-center" style="width:20%">20%</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="w3-button w3-green" onclick="move()">Click Me</button>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```